# Using GROUP BY to group order information (quantity, order_total, etc) based on order_ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a complicated SQL code that I need to edit, so that it GROUPS order information based on the order_ID. Right now, individual products have quantity, product_totals listed (i.e. Orders have multiple products, multiple order_IDs).

Here is my attempt. All I did was add SUM() to order_quantity, product_cost, order_total, and discount. Then I added a GROUP BY o1.id. I got an ERROR message saying GROUP BY was not used properly. I know there is a lot of clutter with this code, I just don't want to remove anything that is necessary as I did not write this code myself.

HERE IS THE CODE I HAVE ATTEMPTED:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reporting.promo_report;
CREATE TABLE reporting.promo_report
SELECT
    v1.id AS variant_id
    , v1.cost_price
    , p1.name AS product
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.parent_category SEPARATOR ", ") AS parent_categories
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.category SEPARATOR ", ") AS sub_categories
FROM `shop`.spree_variants AS v1 
INNER JOIN `shop`.spree_products AS p1 ON v1.product_id = p1.id
INNER JOIN `shop`.spree_products_taxons AS t2 ON p1.id = t2.product_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT
        t3.id
        , t3.name AS category
        , COALESCE(t4.name, t3.name) AS parent_category
    FROM shop.spree_taxons AS t3
    LEFT JOIN shop.spree_taxons AS t4 ON t3.parent_id = t4.id AND t3.parent_id IS NOT NULL) AS t1 ON t2.taxon_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.parent_category NOT IN('City','Themes')
GROUP BY 
    v1.id;
CREATE INDEX i1 ON reporting.tmp_shop_promo_report(variant_id);

SELECT o1.id AS order_id
        , o1.number
        , CAST(o1.completed_at AS DATE) AS order_date
        , SUM(l1.quantity) as order_quantity
        , SUM(l1.price * l1.quantity) AS product_total
        , SUM(adjust.amount) as discount
        , SUM(l1.cost_price) * l1.quantity AS product_cost
        , a2.`code` AS promotion_code

    FROM shop.spree_adjustments AS a1
        INNER JOIN shop.spree_promotion_actions AS p1 
            ON a1.`originator_id` = p1.id 
            AND a1.`originator_type` = 'Spree::PromotionAction'
        INNER JOIN shop.spree_activators AS a2 
            ON p1.`activator_id` = a2.id
        INNER JOIN shop.spree_orders AS o1 
            ON a1.`source_id` = o1.id 
            AND a1.`source_type` = 'Spree::Order'
        INNER JOIN shop.spree_addresses AS a3
            ON o1.bill_address_id = a3.id
        INNER JOIN shop.spree_states AS s1
            ON a3.state_id = s1.id
        INNER JOIN shop.spree_line_items AS l1 
            ON o1.id = l1.order_id
        LEFT JOIN reporting.tmp_shop_promo_report AS t1 
            ON l1.variant_id = t1.variant_id 
        INNER JOIN shop.line_item_histories AS l2 
            ON l1.id = l2.line_item_id
        LEFT JOIN shop.spree_adjustments as adjust
           ON adjust.adjustable_id = o1.id 
                AND adjust.adjustable_type = 'Spree::Order' 
                AND adjust.originator_type = 'Spree::PromotionAction'
                AND adjust.originator_id <> 2770 #free shipping
    WHERE a1.`eligible` = 1
        AND a2.code IN('PROMOCODE')
        AND NULLIF(a2.code,'') IS NOT NULL
        AND o1.completed_at IS NOT NULL;
    GROUP BY o1.id
```

Comment: have you tried `GROUP BY order_id`? `GROUP_BY` can use aliases

Comment: thank u for the edit. I tried order_id. The same ERROR was returned.

Comment: Every column in the select has to either be in the group by or have an aggregate function.  What error are you getting?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  'GROUP BY order_ID"

Comment: Also, this is wrong: SUM(l1.cost_price) * l1.quantity AS product_cost.  The multiplication should be inside the SUM function

Comment: Remove that ; right before the group by

Comment: THANK YOU! The semicolon was the problem. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your error is, but try this:

```
-- as your code
SELECT o1.id AS order_id
    , MAX(o1.number) as number
    , CAST(o1.completed_at AS DATE) AS order_date
    , SUM(l1.quantity) as order_quantity
    , SUM(l1.price * l1.quantity) AS product_total
    , SUM(adjust.amount) as discount
    , SUM(l1.cost_price) * l1.quantity AS product_cost
    , max(a2.`code`) AS promotion_code
-- as your code
```